# Grouped sequence with CSS :nth-child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-lists, pseudo-class

```css
ul,li {
  display: block;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
}
li {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
li:nth-child(2n+2) {
  background: red;
}
li:nth-child(3n+3) {
  background: green;
}
li:nth-child(4n+4) {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
  <li>five</li>
  <li>six</li>
  <li>seven</li>
  <li>eight</li>
  <li>nine</li>
  <li>ten</li>
  <li>eleven</li>
  <li>twelve</li>
</ul>
```

**What I need**:

1. black
2. red
3. green
4. blue
5. black
6. red
7. green
8. blue
9. ...

... how do I achieve this with `:nth-child`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

given the `nth-child` syntax

```css
:nth-child( <an-plus-b>  )
```

you need to iterate using `4n+b`

So,

for background `red` it will be `4n+2` so, `4x0+2`, `4x1+2`, `4x2+2` and so on, which gives you elements 2, 6, 10

for background  `green` it will be `4n+3` so, `4x0+3`, `4x1+3`, `4x2+3` and so on, which gives you elements 3, 7, 11

and for background`'blue`,  it will be `4n+4` so, `4x0+4`, `4x1+4`, `4x2+4` and so on, which gives you elements 4, 8, 12

The remaining elements 1, 5, 9 will be colored `black` by default given your property in `li`

```css
ul,li {
  display: block;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
}
li {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
li:nth-child(4n+2) {
  background: red;
}
li:nth-child(4n+3) {
  background: green;
}
li:nth-child(4n+4) {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
  <li>five</li>
  <li>six</li>
  <li>seven</li>
  <li>eight</li>
  <li>nine</li>
  <li>ten</li>
  <li>eleven</li>
  <li>twelve</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: AFAIK `[ of <selector># ]?` syntax isn't supported anywhere yet.

Comment: @Oriol tbh I got the syntax from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child), but yes seems like WD in selectors level 4 [link](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#nth-child-pseudo)

Comment: Thanks for the explaination!

Comment: Your welcome! @Oriol I updated the answer to not include syntax from the selectors level 4,

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using nth-child as follows

As you need to have black for indices 1,5 and 9 it can be dealt with 4n+1
red for indices 2,6,10 and it can be dealt ith 4n+2

check this snippet

```css
ul,
li {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
li:nth-child(4n+1) {
  background: black;
}
li:nth-child(4n+2) {
  background: red;
}
li:nth-child(4n+3) {
  background: green;
}
li:nth-child(4n+4) {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
  <li>five</li>
  <li>six</li>
  <li>seven</li>
  <li>eight</li>
  <li>nine</li>
  <li>ten</li>
  <li>eleven</li>
  <li>twelve</li>
</ul>
```

Hope it helps